# How to pass non latin string from php to js

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, string

I have a hebrew string in PHP and I need to pass its value to js variable.

I do next in php:

```
<script>
    var phpParams = <?php echo json_encode($jsParams); ?>;
</script>
```

**$jsParams** has a string. When **$jsParams** has an English string everything is working, however when it has a hebrew string **phpParams** value is null.
When I pass hebrew string using ajax mechanism for example like this:

```
<?php
   header('Content-type: application/json');
   $response_array = array('status'=> false, 'cause'=>'נסיון');
   echo json_encode($response_array);
?>
```

I get this json in a browser:

```
{"status":false,"cause":"\u05e0\u05e1\u05d9\u05d5\u05df"}
```

The hebrew is string is encoded into Javascript Escape code.

The question is how can I encode my string to Javascript Escape in php like it is done in ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

My php file's encoding was not unicode. I changed it to UTF-8 and the problem was solved.